# WPF - Triggers on TextBox click

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

I'm trying to write a xaml piece that will set my TextBox's text whenever it gets / loses focus. Currently it looks like this :

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxLogin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="test"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
```

But for some reason whenever I click it, the text doesn't change. I'd like to know why and what are my options to make it work. I also tried other properties like IsStylusCaptured and IsFocused, they didn't work either.

Comment: Try Trigger on IsFocused = True and in the Setter also specify teh Element='TextBoxLogin'

Comment: You want to do it only in XAML ? If so, you can either you IsFocused property

Comment: I have a feeling you didn't read my question.

Comment: @ALazyDoe , so, why do you think I commented? Your post shows XAML only, you want the solution in xaml or in c# ?

Comment: I was talking about your IsFocused property usage proposal. I mentioned already trying that. But yes, I need the answer in XAML only, the c# tag was there by mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Also try removing _Text="TextBox"_ - that makes it work for me

Comment: You can even go with EventTrigger and use GotFocus routed even , tried that ?

Comment: @zackraiyan I think , we can not assign value to`Text` property in `EventTrigger`.

Comment: Thanks @PAulF, it seems like I have to set it via initial setter instead. It works now.

Comment: @GaurangDave , did you try it ?

Comment: @GaurangDave , it can easily be done , but it may require some code behind as well(write some codes just to show off you are a programmer lol)

Comment: @zackraiyan I am talking about using xaml only. He asked that he wanted solution in xaml only. NO code behind. I show off only when I am sure :D

Comment: @GaurangDave , the SHOW OFF part was just sarcasm dude … and you can do it in pure XAML too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is simple, you are setting the `Text` property in the first line :( Either set it in the `STyle` or don't set it :

```
 <TextBox Name="TextBoxLogin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value = "TextHEre"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="test"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
  </TextBox>
```